# What is wrong with my SQL INSERT syntax? quotes or square brackets or...?

Tags: sql, syntax, sql-insert

Here is my SQL INSERT statement

sSqlInsert = "Insert into GruppoColl Values (12343009,TRUE,'30/06/2022 11:57:35',RD,Descrizione,TRONCHETTI_RAME_12.IPT,20050082,'Tipo B','Bombato',0,oransen,'In')"

Here is the error message:

HResult=0x80040E10
Message=No value given for one or more required parameters.

I know 'In' is a reserved word and that 'Tipo B' has spaces so I've put them in single quotes.

Here is the definition of the table in Access:

[image]

Comment: You should really get in the habit of *naming* the columns in your `INSERT` statements, to make sure that the data you're providing is going into the right columns. That being said, the issue here seems to be that you're not quoting *all* of your strings, which you should be doing.

Comment: Many thanks! For some reason I thought I only had to quote strings with spaces in them or other strange characters. I had been doing the named version, but had problems to tried this single statement version.

Comment: Don't think of SQL as some foreign language, but one you're more familiar with. Would you expect C, C++ or C# to treat `abc` the same as `"abc"`? I hope not, so other that the difference in which characters denote a string literal...

Comment: Are but it is a foreign language to me! Can you give me an example of how the columns are named in an SQL INSERT?